# WGSL: Multiplying a vec4f by a mat4f identity matrix produces different results

Tags: vertex-shader, webgpu, wgpu-rs, wgsl

I am trying out WebGPU for the first time and have come across a problem. Normally in other rendering frameworks I would multiply a vec4 my a matrix of all 1s and the output would be the same.

Here is what I expect with this code:

```
@vertex
fn vs_main(in: VertexInput) -> VertexOutput {
    var out: VertexOutput;

    let world_position: vec4f = vec4f(in.position, 0.0, 1.0);

    out.position = world_position;
    out.color = in.color;

    return out;
}
```

[image: the square shows up]

However when I try this:

```
@vertex
fn vs_main(in: VertexInput) -> VertexOutput {
    var out: VertexOutput;

    let world_position: vec4f = mat4x4f(
        1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0,
        1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 
        1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0,
        1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0
    ) * vec4f(in.position, 0.0, 1.0);

    out.position = world_position;
    out.color = in.color;

    return out;
}
```

it gives me this:
[image: nothing shows up]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Each value in resulting `vec4f` of `mat4x4f * vec4f` is the [dot product](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dot_product) of a row in the `mat4x4f` and a column in the `vec4f`.

That is like writing:

```
vec4f(
    max4x4f[0,0]*vec4f[0] + max4x4f[1,0]*vec4f[0] + max4x4f[2,0]*vec4f[0] + max4x4f[3,0]*vec4f[0],
    max4x4f[0,1]*vec4f[1] + max4x4f[1,1]*vec4f[1] + max4x4f[2,1]*vec4f[1] + max4x4f[3,1]*vec4f[1],
    max4x4f[0,2]*vec4f[2] + max4x4f[1,2]*vec4f[2] + max4x4f[2,2]*vec4f[2] + max4x4f[3,2]*vec4f[2],
    max4x4f[0,3]*vec4f[3] + max4x4f[1,3]*vec4f[3] + max4x4f[2,3]*vec4f[3] + max4x4f[3,3]*vec4f[3]
)
```

An [identity matrix](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Identity_matrix) would be:

```
let world_position: vec4f = mat4x4f(
    1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0,
    0.0, 1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 
    0.0, 0.0, 1.0, 0.0,
    0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0
)
```